# What is the number of dashes for a PEM certificate header "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"

Tags: security, x509certificate

There is always 5 dashes before and after or it has no importance?
Is it a convention or part of the RFC?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355046/where-is-the-pem-file-format-specified

Comment: Ok it depends on the OpenSSL implementation