# Delphi Lockbox 3 DOES NOT load public key generated by OpenSSL

Tags: delphi, openssl, lockbox-3

Trying to load RSA public key in Delphi by the use of Lockbox 3 I encounter this error: "(Error) Public key file corrupt, empty or the wrong type."
I have generated a pair of public and private key by OpenSSL using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048   //generate private key
openssl rsa -pubout -in private.pem -out public.pem //generate public key
```

Then in Delphi I used the following code to load libeay32.dll:

```
  sig: TOpenSSL_Signatory;       
  ...
  Sig.Clear;
  Sig.isLoaded := True;
  if Sig.isLoaded then ShowMessage('The OpenSSL library libeay32.dll was loaded successfully.');
```

which always loads successfully.
Then I use the below code to load the public key (i.e. public.pem):

```
f:=TFileStream.Create('c:\keys\public.pem', fmOpenRead);
sig.LoadKeysFromStream(f, [partPublic]);
f.Free;
```

The above code results in the following error: 
"(Error) Public key file corrupt, empty or the wrong type."

How can I solve this problem and load the public key generated by OpenSSL successfully to Delphi?

The public.pem is shown below:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz98tqhhArIOoTtO3HFDW
TcQz4EcSBIc3YejV9GPQq+gMdqO5VsmQhOfHyWAMwOVJ49w/fGib+zyIPmocwCqE
jnQ5UjpNhkO5JIDmlf5NZGI2JcuORg+4Anqgo0D4YGCY04w7Sk8dArLHK+PThPwC
uM2XqyRCpcyTsWRKcH5/G6k6OBBhj5kIeNOy+ZCLeADhNUNiEBXdHQWoMbC+x8Fk
E73KzoOg61BQ7HBMJmfK2p8Shi/wEqD1DPJK3IKkTS+KAB8LvLXdUTDHg1O6FbDn
FfSQWYXzV5MWZR7M3POyX6rjoGRFK+v3mG08S5qEPj/l/PBgNL6wI/aBNkFsYxgf
7QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Can you confirm the public key is in PEM format? `cat` it and see if you see `--- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ---`. If its in `DER` format, add `-outform PEM` to the `openssl rsa` command. If you are in PEM format, try changing `--- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ---` to `--- BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY ---`.

Comment: I add the content of the public.pem file to the question. I also changed --- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY --- to --- BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY --- still the same error as I mentioned in the question. But then I also changed the end tag to -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY----- which leads to the new error: "error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag"

Comment: What does the text form of your public PEM say if you run c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl x509 -in public.pem -inform PEM -noout -text

Comment: after running the command, I get this error: "unable to load certificate
7572:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib"
.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: Saeed/Jan - could that be an issue with line endings?

Comment: I checked the end of lines in notepad++, there is only an "LF" char at the end of each line. By the way, if I change the public.pem to private.pem and use [partPublic, partPrivate] then it is OK and NO error is generated!!! If I use only [partPublic] with private.pem  then I get the same error: "(error) public key file co...".

Answer (score 2):

Method `TOpenSSL_Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream()` is expecting the key to end in ...

```
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This method expects the key to be in PEM (SSLeay) format. SSLeay PEM has base64 content tagged with [-----BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC/PRIVATE KEY-----](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355046/where-is-the-pem-file-format-specified).

To generate a key in the traditional PEM format see ...

- https://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key
- http://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/

You can't change the format simply by renaming the header/footer. You actually have to generate SSLeay PEM by passing the correct options to OpenSSL.

Comment: Could you please write the commands to generate SSLeay PEM keys? The links you provided are not helpful. They do not end up in "-----Begin/End RSA Public/Private key-----". By the way I am using 64bit OpenSSL version 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014. May be I should use older versions, should I?

Comment: This is a separate question and not LockBox3 related. Please post you question, as a new question with the appropriate OpenSSL tag. Please also accept my answer (tick the checkbox).

Comment: This is exactly a lockbox question because I can use the generated keys in C# and php without problem. There is definitly something wrong with lockbox.

Comment: No. You are mistaken. Lockbox3 correctly loads SSLeay formatted PEMs. That is the spec for the function.