# go encoding/pem removes whitespace characters

Tags: go, ssl

I have a Go application that reads and validates certificates, followed by a c++ application that uses the certificates from that location. Golang is automatically removing all (invalid) whitespace characters that are present in a certificate, and thus there are no validation errors, while the c++ application using openssl isn't able to parse this certificate.

```
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pemString))
err := pem.Encode(os.Stdout, block)
if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatal(err)
}
```

From above code, when I decode and encode a cert with whitespace, I get the result with all whitespace removed. Is there a way to identify if cert might have an issue with openssl?

I can check for whitespace, but I want to identify any and all problems that openssl can have with a certificate. Is there a better way to do this?

Sample example: https://play.golang.org/p/HvIRK99g33-

Comment: What is the error you faced with C++?

Comment: Parsing error, invalid cert. With the cert provided in play.golang, you can try `openssl rsa -in key -check`

Comment: That example is a privatekey not a certificate; privatekeys and certificates are different things, though both plus many other things can be and mostly are PEM-encoded in/with OpenSSL. (And exposing your privatekey is a bad idea.) To read a certain type of data like privatekey OpenSSL first decodes the PEM 'armor' if used, decrypts if applicable (which your Go presumably doesn't), and then parses the data as a known ASN.1 type (mostly DER, sometimes BER) and may further check or interpret the results. Which of those do you care about, and for the latter, for which content type(s)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion, with cert I meant it like an umbrella term. My question is more for any kind of pem file, cert, key, csr.
Maybe this would add some context to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40404153/6740589